# Backup encrypted data from Android with broken screen

Tags: adb, data-recovery, fastboot, sony-xperia, broken-screen

short story is as follows: I have a Sony Xperia M2 with display suffering from water damage. It's completely black but it's still working, booting and responding to touch. However, I need to enter my PIN because the device is encrypted. I want to back up some data before I toss that phone. All I would really need to do is enter the 4 digits, then I'd have access to all the files from my PC, but somehow that doesn't work, I tried it a hundred times blind-typing, but I keep messing it up. Does anybody have a solution for that, or a similar phone and a screenshot that could show me what I am doing wrong? (Trying to type the digits, then hitting lower right "Enter" button. Does not work. I get haptic feedback on the "back" button on the lower left corner and I can do something like emergency call in the top middle of the display.)

Apart from that, I tried to access the phone from my Linux laptop. adb does not work at all, probably because USB debug is disabled. I tried to enter fastboot mode and flash a TWRP recovery image like it has been suggested multiple times here to bypass the USB-debug-issue, with no luck. I get into fastboot mode, fastboot sees the device, but when I try to load the boot image, this message pops up:

```
creating boot image...
creating boot image - 382976 bytes
downloading 'boot.img'...
OKAY [  0.014s]
booting...
FAILED (status read failed (No such device))
finished. total time: 5.286s
```

Then the blue LED turns off and gets back to red -> orange, which I assume is nothing but a normal boot.

Does anybody know anything else I could try or why the recovery image does not work? Any suggestion is really much appreciated.